# Urllib request not returning 304 when it should

Tags: python, http, urllib

I've recently been relearning Python and I made a little script to return contents from a url. However, when adding the "If-Modified-Since" header, the script never gives me a 304 error. Even when the content hasn't been modified.

The script I currently have is:

```
""" HTTP SERVICES

Program intended to demonstrate the usage of the urllib.request
module (previously urllib2).

"""

import urllib.request as urllib # For getting files off the web
import time  # For delaying purposes


# Getting the actual XML file
request = urllib.Request("some website")

# Get data first time
opener = urllib.build_opener()
feed_data = opener.open(request)
print(feed_data.read())


for i in range(1, 11):
    time.sleep(1)

    # Does not return 304
    request.add_header("If-Modified-Since",
                        feed_data.headers.["Last-Modified"])
    feed_data = opener.open(request)
    print(feed_data.read())
```

Can anyone explain why it's not return a 304 error?

Comment: Are you sure revalidation based content caching is implemented on the server side? Can you get a 304 response from, say curl or a regular browser?

Comment: @shevron I've not checked that, in fact, that may be the problem. I tried running the script with google and some other websites but none of them seemed to be returning a 304